# Sharepoint list search to update multiple controls

Tags: list, search, spgridview

I want to create a page it will have the following 3 components on it.

1. A Dropdown list populated with colors.
2. A Custom list
3. Web part with some textual information

When the user chooses a color and clicks the 'Ok' button, the Custom list should filter based on this and the textual information would also change to show some text.

Is the best way to do this create a web part with a dropdown list, SPGridView and label?
And then handle the button event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it is the most general way. The choice between user control, web part and custom application page depends on the requirements, like how many times will it be used in pages, will it be on the master page, should you have limitations on where to use it etc.

For example,

- If your required component will be in master page or custom page layout it is suitable to develop it as a user control (ascx)
- If your component should be addable on any site and any page and it needs user/power user customization then it should be web part.
- If your component should have some static place, like a url, then it should be a application page etc.