# Is it bad practice to copy and paste pages in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, visual-studio, page-layout

I am a new sharepoint developer.  I am creating a web template from scratch in visual studio.

I am finding it time consuming when creating/editing pages in visual studio e.g. adding web parts to pages etc.

To combat this what i have started to do is create the pages in sharepoint designer (add web parts to the pages etc). After i have done this i copy and paste the markup into visual studio.

Is this bad practice? Are there any better ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good actually for saving time, some people also export templates from SharePoint to save time.

The markup won't be as streamlined as if you had manually coded it, but when you save time, you save money, and saving money is always best.

There will be very little if any markup/instructions that will slow down the pages at all.

Comment: thanks for replying. could you also give this a bash please. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/51085/sharepoint-list-search-to-update-multiple-controls